# hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad error in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am getting below error when i am trying to access my Jenkins server,

```
hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException: java.lang.Error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:234)
Caused by: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException: java.lang.Error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:269)
    at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:44)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:910)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:809)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:82)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:78)
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:222)
Caused by: java.lang.Error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:109)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder$TaskImpl.run(TaskMethodFinder.java:169)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:282)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$7.runTask(Jenkins.java:899)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:210)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:105)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.OrderRetainingMap.entrySet(OrderRetainingMap.java:77)
    at java.util.HashMap.putMapEntries(HashMap.java:511)
    at java.util.HashMap.putAll(HashMap.java:784)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.OrderRetainingMap.<init>(OrderRetainingMap.java:36)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.FieldDictionary.buildMap(FieldDictionary.java:135)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.FieldDictionary.fieldsFor(FieldDictionary.java:76)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:127)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doMarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:149)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.marshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:108)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:69)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:43)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.start(TreeMarshaller.java:82)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.marshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:37)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.marshal(XStream.java:898)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.marshal(XStream.java:887)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.toXML(XStream.java:860)
    at hudson.XmlFile.write(XmlFile.java:178)
    at hudson.model.Descriptor.save(Descriptor.java:758)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitTool.onLoaded(GitTool.java:108)
    ... 13 more
```

At the end of error file,i thought may be error related to Git tool. So i have also removed git-client plugin from /var/lib/jenkins/plugins. But after that it will show error unable to read `config.xml` file even though file is already there in /var/lib/jenkins/config.xml

I need git-client plugin also. I don't know how to solve this problem.
Please help if anyone know about this issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I met this `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1` error before. It was because I started jenkins server with lower java version(maybe 1.6 or older?). And at the end I resolved this issue by starting jenkins with a newer version of java.

Comment: Thank you for the response. How did you upgrade java version in Jenkins?

Answer (score 4):

I stopped jenkins service and deleted that file and folder from

```
Jenkins_HOME/plugin
cloudbees-folder.jpi
cloudbees-folder [directory]
```

and then restart jenkins service.

Comment: Although Jenkins successfully boots after this, it nuked references to the existing jobs/workspaces, requiring us to rebuild the (unfortunately manually created) jobs from scratch - is this an end-all be(e)-all solution?

Answer (score 4):

Removing plugins from jenkins directory and restarting jenkins worked for me.

For my  linux system, I did following:

1. goto jenkins home "/var/lib/jenkins/"
2. ls plugins //plugins directory inside jenkins home exists
3. Make sure to copy plugins directory to some other path for backup
4. cd plugins
5. sudo rm -rf ./* Remove entire contents inside plugins directory.
6. Restart jenkins with command: 
   sudo service jenkins restart
7. Restart jenkins link in browser and it opened normally.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41241

The issue get resolves when you delete all the plugins from Jenkins Installation folder.
Follow these steps (Windows installation)

1. Go to Jenkins installation folder in "C:\Program files\Jenkins\Plugins" copy all the files in some other drive for future reference.
2. Stop Jenkins server : Go to Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Administrative Tools\Services search for Jenkins and stop it
3. Delete all the files in the "C:\Program files\Jenkins\Plugins"
   folder
4. Restart the Jenkins your good to go but all the plugins will have to be reinstalled
5. Refer the "Plugins " folder which you have copied in some other destination and install the plugins

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this type of error comes when Jenkins find some chaos inside its plugin or config folders arose due to any of our effort to upgrade/downgrade/update.

The simple solution is , we need to login to Jenkins and go to the location where we were trying to do the modification, and try to revert it back by deleting or modifying to its previous state.

e.g I got this similar issue while trying to upgrade/downgarde the credentials plugin. So I went to `/home/Jenkins/plugins` and deleted all the files related to credentials and restarted the Jenkins from tomcat.

```
/home/Jenkins/plugins
rm -rf credentials.jpi.pinned
rm -rf credentials.jpi.disabled
rm -rf credentials.jpi
rm -rf credentials.bak
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I installed a new JDK 1.8, without uninstalling existing 1.7. 
Try uninstalling newer jdk (1.8 in my case) solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the plugins Matrix-auth.jpi and PrioritySorter.jpi are causing problems. When they are deleted it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Stop the jenkins using systemctl stop jenkins and kill the process by using kill -9  and try restarting the jenkins using systemctl start jenkins or run the jenkins jar file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).